# NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableArray array]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am reading a book on Cocoa, and I've got to a section where the author declares a property, `@property (strong) NSMutableDictionary *characters;` And then initialises it like so: `self.characters = [NSMutableArray array];` I would be very grateful is someone could explain what is going on during the initialisation. I know `[NSMutableArray array]` returns an empty array, but how does this relate to the NSMutableDictionary?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a typo and it'll even compile without a warning because `[NSMutableArray array]` returns `id`. As soon as code executed that called an `NSMutableDictionary` method it would crash with `unrecognized selector sent to instance NSMutableArray`. If you called `count` on it though, it would not crash because both types have that method, therefore, the compiler will be happy to compile it, because you've told it its an `NSMutableDictionary` and the runtime will find that method and call it because in reality it's an `NSMutableArray`. Its definitely a typo, I can't think of a good reason you'd ever want to "take advantage" of this possibility.

Comment: Actually, the convenience constructors won't show a warning.  The compiler has no problem with `NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableArray array];`, but `NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` will give you an "incompatible types" warning.

Comment: Under ARC, I believe `alloc` now implies a return type of `instancetype` and it will warn.

Comment: Yeah, @AaronBrager mentions that in his comment above.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a typo. It’s not possible to initialize an `NSMutableDictionary` object with an `NSMutableArray` alloc/init call.

Comment: I don't think it is a typo. I have the Xcode project with this code in it and the code compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: It compiles because `array` returns `id`. Try to use that "dictionary" for anything and you'll get a nice crash.

Answer (score 1):

The lesson might be showing you that how you declare a property is just a guide for you to use while writing your code. At run-time, whatever class you actually allocate (in this case, NSMutableArray) is the type of object actually allocated and stored into memory. An exception will be thrown later on if you try to use an unrecognized selector (like setObject:forKey:) on the object.

Your specific implementation might not cause an exception, since both of these classes respond to some of the same selectors, like count, and they both work with fast enumeration.

There is typically no benefit to doing things this way, though. Things should be what they say they are.

Side note: once you get more comfortable with this stuff, look into an Objective C feature called Forward Invocation, which allows classes to respond to selectors they haven't implemented, by forwarding the request to another class.

Comment: I'll make a stronger statement: this kind of type punning is a *terrible* idea. If you need a dictionary, use a dictionary; if you need an array, use an array.

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableArray array];` This will create `NSMutableArray` object.

```
Xcode Product menu-> generate output ->Assembly file

L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_:
    .quad   _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableArray
```

`NSArray` manage ordered collection of objects. `NSDictionary` manage associations of keys and values. You should not Initializes `NSMutableDictionary` with `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  // return type is NSMutableArray

Warning :Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableDictionary *' with an expression of type 'NSMutableArray *'  

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableArray array]; // return type is id + (id)array  

NO Warnings
```